# using Regular Expressions and tags to extract portion of text

Tags: .net, regex, extract

So I have a text file that is having special tags like:

```
{A1}
Text 1
{A1}

{A2}
Text 2
{A2}
```

How can I extract from the text using reg-ex the portion `Text 2` or `Text 1` ..?
So I what to be able to extract only what is between tags A1 or only what is between Tags A2 .. not all of them ... at once!
thanks!

Comment: Can the special tags be nested?

Comment: no ... all the tags are in line ....one after the other ... like in the army :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can do something like this:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(YOUR_TEXT, @"\{(?<Tag>\w+).*?\}(?<text>\w+).*?\{\k<Tag>\}", "$2");
```

Nested tags are not suppoerted.

Comment: Well, if you would check you would see that it returns text

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following regular expression if you assume that the document is well-formed and that your tags are not nested:

```
@"({.*?})(.*)\1"
```

Example:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"({.*?})(.*?)\1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(s)) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value.Trim());
}
```

Output:

```
Text 1
Text 2
```

Comment: and If I need only Text 1 or only Text 2 ..?